# How to watch for new network connections TTL

Tags: linux, trace, perf, ttl, ebpf

I need to watch for new connections accept() TTL and collect them for further investigation.

tcpdump can show TTL for packets, but can't show only accept() connections.
I've tried iovisor/bcc and [tcpaccept](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/tcpaccept.py) is doing well, but doesn't show TTL.

Cloudflare has [great post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/epbf_sockets_hop_distance/) about extracting TTL from connection, but it works only with socket you've created.

Does anybody know how make this right?

UPDATED: not accept() but inet_csk_accept()

Comment: Who says `tcpdump` can't do that?!  `tcpdump -i <interface> "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-ack) != 0"`

Comment: @tink it floods all packets to CLI and tcpaccept show only events from kretprobe__inet_csk_accept

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a result of this question I've written a [post](https://medium.com/@akme/from-ttl-to-hop-distance-849f00f9b4e7?source=friends_link&sk=73851d4d346cee963e4b2fe67127026f).
tcpdump can be used to get TTL, but it makes it for every packet and to get TTL for inet_csk_accept() we need to go deeper with eBPF, so I've created an [issue](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/2395) at iovisor/bcc repo.